# Some methods have its returned value persisted only if other fields are changed before PreUpdate

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-update

My `Budget` entity has some methods to be executed on `PrePersist` and `PreUpdate`. The methods are:

```
/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function generateNextPaymentDate()
{
    if ($this->getStartsAt() !== null) {
        $date = new \DateTime($this->getStartsAt()->format('Y-m-d'));
        return $date->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $this->getCheckFor() . 'D'));
    }
}

/**
 * @return decimal
 */
public function calculateTotalBudgetPrice()
{
    $totalBudgetPrice = 0;

    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $totalBudgetPrice += $item->getPrice();
    }

    return $totalBudgetPrice;
}

/**
 * @return decimal
 */
public function calculateInstallmentRatePrice()
{
    return $this->calculateTotalBudgetPrice() / $this->getInstallmentRate();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function onPreEvents()
{
    $this->setNextPaymentDate($this->generateNextPaymentDate());
    $this->setInstallmentRatePrice($this->calculateInstallmentRatePrice());
    $this->setTotalBudgetPrice($this->calculateTotalBudgetPrice());
}
```

The methods `calculateInstallmentRatePrice()` and `calculateTotalBudgetPrice()` uses the attributes of the `Product` entity, which is a collection form inside of `Budget`.

The issue I've noticed is that these methods only have their returned value persisted into the database if I modify one or more field of the `Budget` form. If I do not, the values from these two methods are still correct but simply not changed in the base.

I do not understand why it happens. Have I missed some logic?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate) for the `preUpdate` event you will see this info:

> Changes to fields of the passed entities are not recognized by the
>   flush operation anymore, use the computed change-set passed to the
>   event to modify primitive field values

So, you would need to use the `setNewValue()` function to modify your entity, doing something like:

```
$eventArgs->setNewValue('nextPaymentDate', $this->generateNextPaymentDate());
```

Comment: The `generateNextPaymentDate()` method is working fine, it successfully update with no poblems. The `calculateTotalBudgetPrice()` and `calculateInstallmentRatePrice()` are too, but they only have their new values persisted into the database if I also modify another field of the form, get it?

Comment: Read my answer, it's explained there

Comment: It may work for some fields, but the only way to make it work for all fields is to use `setnewvalue`

Comment: I have tried it, but I am having problems because it is saying that my field `totalBudgetPrice` and `installmentRatePrice` are not valid fields of the `Budget` entity. I read that this method only reads the fields that have changed, but I do not change these fields, the methods does, I only change the field `meters` from `Product` collection and then, based on this new value, these two methods calculate the new values for those fields. Besides, the `preUpdate()` method was executed only because I have changed another field from `Budget`. Same situation as before.